# How to convert char[] to string in java?

Tags: java, string

> char[] c = string.toCharArray();

but how to convert c back to String type?
thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the `String` constructors?

Comment: +1 I just did research - first google result

Comment: Any "stupid" question can be useful if it is Google-d faster than looking into any docs.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use [`String.valueOf(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#copyValueOf%28char%5B%5D%29):

```
String.valueOf(c)
```

Under the hood, this calls the [`String(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29) constructor. I always prefer factory-esque methods to constructors, but you could have used `new String(c)` just as easily, as several other answers have suggested.

---

```
char[] c = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
String s = String.valueOf(c);

System.out.println(s);
```

```
xyz
```

Comment: note that this returns the string "null" (not the value, the string with the actual word "null" in it) if the char[] is null. Not so with new String(c) which I think will NPE

Comment: Scratch that - it'll NPE in either case. (It's the String.valueOf(Object) that returns "null")... This potential NPE btw was the reason I searched this question in the first place - it'd be nice to replace String with char[] without having to do null checks... IMO it _is a valid question_

Answer (score 3):

You can use the String constructor:

`String(char[] value);`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
char[] chars = ...
String string = String.valueOf(chars);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
char[] c = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String str = new String(c); // "abc"
```

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5b%5d%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
char[] c = {'h', 'e','l', 'l', 'o'};
String s = new String(c);
```